# Can I use Asp.Net Application User in SignalR messages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

Hello,  I'm starting with private messages between ASP.net users, using SignalR, everything Works fine if I'm using ConnectionId - s, In this way I can take recipient's ConnectionId and send private message to this person. Now about problem, I want store messages in database and load them on login, I'm using Standard membership of ASP.net mvc5 application, so after reconnect ConnectionId is changing. I was reading article [Mapping SignalR Users to Connections](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections), I but cannot understand how to use IUserProvider Can you explain me how to make this taks. lot of thanks.
Here is my hub code:

```
[HubName("chatHub")]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{

    static List<ApplicationUser> Users = new List<ApplicationUser>();
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
    }


    public void SendPM(string name, string privatemessage, string userid)
    {
       //This line not Works I've commented it but filling It's correct way
       //Clients.User(userid).addPM(name, privatemessage);   
       Clients.Client(userid).addPM(name, privatemessage);
    }

    public void Connect(string userName)
    {
        var id = Context.ConnectionId;
        var appuser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == userName);
        var dbUsers = db.Users.ToList();

        if (!Users.Any(x => x.ConnectionId == id))
        {
            Users.Add(new ApplicationUser { ConnectionId = id, UserName = userName, Id = appuser.Id });


            Clients.Caller.onConnected(id, userName, Users);


            Clients.AllExcept(id).onNewUserConnected(id, userName);
        }
    }


    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        var item = Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == Context.ConnectionId);
        if (item != null)
        {
            Users.Remove(item);
            var id = Context.ConnectionId;
            Clients.All.onUserDisconnected(id, item.UserName);
        }

        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should find your answer here: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#IUserIdProvider

Answer (score 1):

The article says:

> By default, there will be an implementation that uses the user's IPrincipal.Identity.Name as the user name.

This means that for the mapping to work, you need to make user that users are logged in (authorized) when calling SignalR hub. The easiest way to ensure this is to add `[Authorize]` attribute to `ChatHub` and the controller that returns chat view.

If user is authorized, you can retrieve his username from current context by calling:

```
   var username = Context.User.Identity.Name;
```

Then, the following should work (without the need to provide your own `IUserIdProvider`):

```
public void SendPM(string name, string privatemessage, username)
{
   Clients.Client(username).addPM(name, privatemessage);
}
```